# Create DLL file using C# to use in java

Tags: c#, java, .net, dll, jacob

Hey guys I'm java developer however I need to work around c#. In my company we are facing some issues in java so we decided to call dll function through java. I wrote `.cs` file as follow

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Com
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), Guid("F2F37A34-A440-4e82-A941-996056AADD88")]
    public class Calculation
    {
        [DebuggerNonUserCode]
        public Calculation()
        {
        }
        public int sum(int x, int y)
        {
            return checked(x + y);
        }
        public int subtract(int x, int y)
        {
            return checked(x - y);
        }
        public int multi(int x, int y)
        {
            return checked(x * y);
        }
        public double Div(int x, int y)
        {
            if (y != 0)
            {
                return (double)x / (double)y;
            }
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

To create DLL File I'm using `csc.exe /t:library /out:D:/test.dll`

To Register DLL File I'm using `RegAsm /verbose /nologo /codebase D:\test.dll`

To Unregister DLL File I'm using `RegAsm.exe /unregister D:\test.dll`

I'm able to call this DLL in java program using `jacob` library. My problem is when I'm trying to call same dll using Applet it throws exception.

So to call DLL over network/browser do I have to follow other things?

OR

Is there any other way to create DLL file or say parameter I've to set to use it over network/browser...

Comment: *"My problem is when I'm trying to call same dll using Applet it throws exception"*...is the applet signed?  I'd be surprised if you can load native libraries within the applet sandbox...

Comment: Yes applet is signed..

Comment: You might also like to post the exception...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446464/com-jacob-com-comfailexception-cant-co-create-object